# Got mod tools, now what?

Tags: discussion, faq, 10k-tools

I recently got the [moderator tools privilege](https://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools). How can I use this power for the greater good of Android Enthusiasts?

Answer (score 8):

## Deletion

Besides many other features the *moderator tools focus heavily on deletion/undeletion management*. One action you can take is to review the closed questions for possible deletion candidates. But make sure that you don't vote to delete a question that is [closed as duplicate](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/). Furthermore, use your common sense if a question should really be deleted: Does  it, although it is closed, may provide valuable information? Finally, don't waste your delete vote on questions with a negative score, that is not locked and has no answers. [It will get deleted after 30 days automatically by the system.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/156683)

Use the magic of search queries to find possible deletion candidates:

- [Closed questions with "best" in title](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=title:best%20closed:1)
- (extend list here)

## Reopen votes

Once in a while we change our policy about what is considered off-topic. [For example how we handle questions about rooting.](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/790/should-we-revisit-our-how-do-i-root-x-policy) Which means that we have to reopen some questions that where considered off topic/not constructive/etc before. The mod tools provide an easy way to see were votes accumulate. [Use that and cast your vote accordingly.](https://android.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last30days)

## Checking flagged posts

This helps to keep our site clean. Though you might not be able to directly close/delete/migrate stuff, adding your flag moves the item up in the queue and helps moderators to quickly recognize the "important ones" (see also [Dealing with obvious spam](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/dealing-with-obvious-spam)).

## Anonymous and low rep post feedback

Is actually a pretty nifty feature. [Overrated posts](https://android.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/overrated?filter=all) which got a lot of negative feedback  could be a possible problem that needs to be fixed. On the other hand [underrated](https://android.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/underrated?filter=all) posts may deserve a little upvote love from you.

## Anything else?

Most other functionality is already covered in the new review system.

## See also

- [What are the moderation tools available to high-reputation users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users)
- [How to behave now I've got the 10K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20812/how-to-behave-now-ive-got-the-10k)
- [Is there a "how to" for the 10K moderator tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86554/is-there-a-how-to-for-the-10k-moderator-tools)
- [I'm 10K now at SO, what's the next thing to do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65788/im-10k-now-at-so-whats-the-next-thing-to-do)

Comment: This answer should have a "[Spoiler Alert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoiler_%28media%29)" somewhere ;)

Comment: Hehe, nothing you shouldn't already know from the moderator tools page. :)

Comment: My goodness, but can we emphasize that **Delete** ability? There is a lot of drek out there on the site that desperately needs to be gone forever, but I seem to be the only person casting delete votes.

Comment: That's why it's mentioned first in the list. :)