# How to handle the reopening of the "How do I root X?" questions?

Tags: discussion, voting

This is a follow up on ["Should we revisit our “How do I root X?”](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/790/should-we-revisit-our-how-do-i-root-x-policy) policy. Now, with the reopen review queue in place, it should be easy to reopen the previously cosed questions.

How should we handle this in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following procedure:

1. Search with a suitable query for closed how to root questions. [Example.](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=how%20root%20closed:1)
2. Nominate the question for reopening
3. If the question is reopend, [add it to the canonical question's cw answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/1465) and make sure that the question is tagged with the correct device tag.

Comment: Straightforward.  We'd just need to double-check for duplicates I suppose.  I'm also wondering if this is something mods should just do immediately, at least for the decently formulated questions.