# "How to root" questions for different builds?

Tags: discussion, questions

I know we allow 1 "How do I root" question per device and in [this meta post](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/790/7574) it says:

> ....one post per device. These questions should each have one answer with a complete rooting guide that addresses all software versions,

However, what do we do if a user is asking for a rooting solution for a different build than the one in an already existing post? For example, do we consider https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35826/7574 a duplicate of [How to root the new version of the ONE X](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/32598/7574)? Even though it isn't an exact duplicate since the build numbers differ? If we close the question, the user may never get a good answer?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, there would be a separate answer for the different build.

However, I think it's not unreasonable to leave both questions open. The questions have a clear difference, even if it's only slight. If it turns out that the answer to both are basically the same, they can always be merged later. It would be good to put explicit links between them, as well as some language saying why they're not duplicates.

(Close-as-duplicate is more for situations where you have "How do I make the turtle move in Logo?" and "In Logo, how do I move the turtle?" questions, which are obviously just different phrasings of the same question.)

Comment: I tend to agree with you. However, the question I mentioned has been closed now as a duplicate, which seems to indicate more people disagree with you? I guess the only options available to the OP are: 1) hoping the question gets reopened, or 2) place a bounty on the original question and mention that he is looking for a solution for a different build.

Comment: Closure is not an end state. All the OP needs to do is point out why his/her question isn't a duplicate. The Bounty isn't a bad idea, though.